# JQuery - get a scrollable elements current height

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering how in JQuery I can get the height of an element that has overflow hidden and a height set on it.

I've tried googling for quite a while, but I just can't find anything. Anything I find gives the total height as if it wasn't scrollable, but finding the opposite seems to be difficult.

**Edit**: Turns out I was doing it on the wrong element. Protip: Pick the height of the scrollable element, not what's inside it...

Answer (score 0):

**Edited based on edit:**

- `*` Wildcard is set to reset browser `margin`s.

Check the following example with [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight):

```js
var getHeight = $('body').prop('scrollHeight');
alert(getHeight);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>stuff</div>
```